# Spring Cloud Dataflow ticktock example fails in CloudFoundry

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to get most basic example for Spring Cloud Dataflow running on CloudFoundry.
I've followed the steps here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-admin-cloudfoundry/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started to make the admin app available in my org/space.
Then I tried to create the most basic example from http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/, namely to create the "ticktock" stream:

```
dataflow:>stream create ticktock --definition "time | log" --deploy
```

I can see that both apps ticktock-time and ticktock-log are created in the space, the needed service "redis" is bound to these apps and they try to start. Unfortunately they don't start completely, because they have problem to access "redis" service. In the log we find:

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
>   refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to
>   start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to
>   start bean 'inputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot
>   get Jedis connection; nested exception is
>   redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get
>   a resource from the pool

which eventually is caused by

> Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Am I missing some configuration step in between?

Alexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with our deployer using the `master` branch of the Java buildpack. Try these settings for the Dataflow Server:

```
cf set-env s-c-dataflow-server CLOUDFOUNDRY_BUILDPACK https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#v3.6
cf restage s-c-dataflow-server
```

Also, be aware that we currently launch apps using "streamname-module" as part of the URL so unless you use unique stream names you might collide with other users and get a "400 Bad Request" error.